# Error on spring boot starter web project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I'm tying to start a spring starter project.

I create the project from spring tool suite. after that I run "mvn clean install" but I got this.

¿How can I solve this problem?

```
    C:\code\HUBLCY\ws\HubNvo>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HubNvo 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.3/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.3.pom
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.3/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.3.pom
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.3/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.3.pom
Downloading: https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/maven-milestones/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.3/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.3.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.3/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.3.pom
Downloading: https://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom/2.2.0/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.2.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom/2.2.0/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.2.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom/2.2.0/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.2.0.pom
Downloading: https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/maven-milestones/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom/2.2.0/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.2.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom/2.2.0/shrinkwrap-resolver-bom-2.2.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-8/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-8.pom
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-8/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-8.pom
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-8/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-8.pom
Downloading: https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/maven-milestones/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-8/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-8.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-8/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-8.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.518 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-16T15:53:16-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/127M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hub: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.gh.app:hub:jar:0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE -> org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to repo2 (https://repo2.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
"cmd" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are unable to get the dependencies you need.
Something to do with org.jboss.shrinkwrap.

> Failed to execute goal on project hub: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project com.gh.app:hub:jar:0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE ->
>   org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for
>   org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3
>   from/to repo2 (https://repo2.maven.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

I would verify that the maven instance you are using to build with is not overriding the repo location you should be using for Springboot.

Also, try cleaning out your ~/.m2/repository folder then running clean install again.